# What method definition should I use for creating an extension method on IEquatable<T>

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I was going to create an `In` extension method on `int`, when I realized, if I use IEquatable I'd get the extension on all primitive types.  This is my current implementation

```
public static bool In<T>(this T value, params T[] values) where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    return values.Contains(value);
}
```

It works just fine `if(i.In(1,3,7))` for ints, but the `where T: IEquatable<T>` just looks wrong to me.  Is this the correct way to define the generic method?

Comment: Why not just write `(new int[] {1,3,7}).Contains(i)`

Comment: @ChristianHayter I believe it reads easier `if(today.In(Monday,Tuesday))` vs `if(new int[] {Monday, Tuesday}).Contains(today))`

Comment: interesting and kinda related, but not an answer: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx

Comment: Fair enough, your call. I suggest you replace your `In` method body with a call to `Contains` though. That way you don't have to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @ChristianHayter that is exactly what I suggested in my answer

Comment: @lazyberezovsky The difference is that you're not actually answering the question as asked; you should have just posted a comment.

Comment: @Servy no, I should not - my answer is about achieving same result with simple way. If you asking about parsing xml with `StreamReader`, I'll give you solution with linq to xml.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky He didn't ask for a better way to implement the method, he's asking if this type of signature is appropriate for such a method.  You didn't even address that issue.  Improving the implementation would be fine *in addition to answering the question* but not *instead of answering the question*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have looks right to me.  You're saying that the type must implement `IEquatable<T>` for its own type.

You could also extend it to say that the type you're comparing against can be a different type that implements `IEquatable<T>` for the `value`:

```
public static bool In<T, U>(this T value, params U[] values) where U : IEquatable<T>
{
    bool result = false;
    foreach (U instance in values)
    {
        if (instance.Equals(value))
        {
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Are there any Framework types that implement `IEquatable` for anything other than themselves, or is there anyplace where Microsoft recommends such an implementation?  Note that while `IEquatable<T>` could have been contravariant with respect to `T`, Microsoft didn't declare it that way, likely because even though interface could theoretically support contravariance, it shouldn't be used with inheritable classes.

Comment: Looks like [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) that the type parameter should be the implementing type.  So, you're right, @supercat, probably not a good choice.

Comment: Although I didn't care for the second part of your answer, "the type must implement IEquatable<T> for its own type." was the best English explanation given of the other answers and helped me understand what was going on.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `this T value` as a method argument, use `this IEquatable<T> value` instead. Then you need no constraint on T and you also define it only for IEquatable .

Comment: That's a performance problem for value types because it causes boxing.

Comment: @usr so that would be doing an implicit cast on my int (or wherever other types satisfy the constraint) to an IEquatable<int>?  And if I use the where constraint a compile time check is done to ensure that it meets that constraint, but then no cast is needed?

Comment: Casting to `IEquatable<int>` requires boxing first. With generics there is no need to change any type as the variable is typed as `T`. It is always a perfect type match.

Comment: @usr is right, this requires boxing if T is a value type. I can't come up with a solution that would avoid this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct. (Not sure what else to say. I have defined the same method and it works fine although I came to believe that I don't like the style of it. That's subjective, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

`where T: IEquatable<T>` is a [generic constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b0scde8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), so it's perfectly well and, moreover, is preferred way to restrict usage of generic method/class/whatever with a limited set of types.